# Debug port issues. An internal error occurred during: "Updating focus". The process debug port is already in use

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, networking

There are multiple issues that might be connected. I have no idea what may cause this but the main one are debug ports usage. It looks like this:
[image]

There is output from `netstat -nlp` where the list is much longer like:

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8650          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8618          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8651          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8619          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8652          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8620          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8653          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8621          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8654          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8622          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8687          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8623          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8655          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8688          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8656          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8624          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8657          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8625          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8658          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8626          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8627          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8660          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8628          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8661          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8629          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8630          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8631          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8632          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8600          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8665          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8633          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8601          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8634          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8602          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8635          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8603          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8636          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8604          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8637          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8605          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8670          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8638          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8606          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8671          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8639          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8607          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8672          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8608          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8640          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8609          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8641          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8674          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8642          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8610          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8611          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8643          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8612          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8644          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8677          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8645          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8678          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8646          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8614          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8679          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8647          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8615          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8648          :::*                    LISTEN      29331/pluginloader.
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8616          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8681          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8649          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8617          :::*                    LISTEN      28796/java
```

This is more Console out:

```
[2014-11-10 08:50:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8648 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8649 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8651 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8652 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8655 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8656 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8657 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8660 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 192.168.56.101:5555
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]'.../sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - adb]ADB server didn't ACK
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - adb]* failed to start daemon *
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8605 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8610 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8614 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8615 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8616 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8617 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8619 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8620 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8621 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8622 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8624 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8625 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8628 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8629 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8632 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8634 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8635 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8636 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8637 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8638 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:53 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8639 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8640 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8641 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8642 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8643 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8644 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8646 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8647 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8648 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8649 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8651 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8652 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8655 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8656 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8657 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:50:56 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8660 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:51:36 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 192.168.56.101:5555
[2014-11-10 08:52:16 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 192.168.56.101:5555
[2014-11-10 08:52:31 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-11-10 08:52:31 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8605 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8610 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8614 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8615 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8616 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8617 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8619 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8620 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8621 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8622 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8624 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8625 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8628 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8629 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8632 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8634 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8635 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8636 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8637 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8638 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8639 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8640 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8641 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:35 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:37 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:37 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:37 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:37 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:37 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:37 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:37 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:43 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:43 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:43 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:43 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:43 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:43 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:43 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:44 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-11-10 08:52:44 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
[2014-11-10 08:52:44 - hierarchyviewer]Failed to remove forward for device 500c235a: Connection refused
[2014-11-10 08:52:45 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 2
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8605 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8610 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8614 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8615 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8616 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8617 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8619 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8620 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8621 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8622 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8624 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8625 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8628 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8629 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8632 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8634 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8635 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8636 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8637 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8638 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8639 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8640 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:46 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8641 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:49 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:49 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:54 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:52:54 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:00 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:00 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:05 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:12 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:12 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:12 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:12 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:12 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:12 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:12 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:16 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:16 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:16 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:16 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:16 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:16 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:16 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:17 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:19 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:19 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:19 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:19 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:19 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:19 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:19 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:20 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:20 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:20 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:20 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:20 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:20 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:20 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:22 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:22 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:22 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:22 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:22 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:22 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:22 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:28 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:28 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:28 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:28 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:28 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:29 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:29 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:29 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:29 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:29 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:29 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:29 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:31 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:31 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:31 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:31 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:31 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:31 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:31 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:32 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:32 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:32 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:32 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:32 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: lenovo-lenovo_a820-0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:32 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:32 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8605 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8610 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8614 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8615 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8616 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8617 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8619 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8620 for debugger
[2014-11-10 08:53:33 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8621 for debugger
```

Any ideas how to prevent this port issue?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Restart from Eclipse out:

[image]

From console seems to `restart` the `adb`, but with no effect.

Comment: Did you try to restart `adb` ?